# Make Custom Footer For Specific Report

Tags: openerp-7

I have a question
when I try to override request_quotation.rml to be like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<document filename="requestforquotation.pdf">
   <template title="Purchase Order" author="OpenERP S.A.(sales@openerp.com)" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate id="first">
      <frame id="first" x1="15.0" y1="42.0" width="539" height="758"/>
      <pageGraphics>



         <!-- ======================== footer =========================== -->
        <place x="33" y="55cm" width="530.0" height="205.0">
                <blockTable colWidths="265" style="Table1">
                            <tr><td><para style="normal2-center">:‫التالية‬ ‫الشروط‬ ‫توافر‬ ‫حالة‬ ‫في‬ ‫فقط‬ ‫أعاله‬ ‫املذكور‬ ‫التاريخ‬ ‫في‬ ‫املبلغ‬ ‫بدفع‬ ‫الشركة‬ ‫تلتزم‬
‫البضاعة‬ ‫تسليم‬ ‫تاريخ‬ ‫من‬ ‫يومني‬ ‫أقصى‬ ‫بحد‬ ‫املبلغ‬ ‫بنفس‬ ‫املورد‬ ‫من‬ ‫البيع‬ ‫فاتورة‬ ‫أصل‬ ‫تسليم‬
</para></td></tr>
                        </blockTable>
                    </place>
        </pageGraphics>
    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
  <stylesheet>
    <blockTableStyle id="Standard_Outline">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Tableau1">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Tableau2">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Table_Product_Header_Title">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="0,-1" stop="0,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="1,-1" stop="1,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="2,-1" stop="2,-1"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Table_Product_Line">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="0,-1" stop="0,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="1,-1" stop="1,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="2,-1" stop="2,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="3,-1" stop="3,-1"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <initialize>
      <paraStyle name="all" alignment="justify"/>
    </initialize>
    <paraStyle name="P1" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="Standard"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_header" fontSize="12.0" leading="15" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="12.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_tblheader_Details" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="6.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_8" fontSize="8.0" leading="10" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="6.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Bold_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Centre_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Right_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="RIGHT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="Space bet user and signature" fontSize="4.0" leading="5" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <images/>
  </stylesheet>
  <story>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[repeatIn(objects,'order')]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ setLang(order.partner_id.lang) ]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <blockTable colWidths="250.0,59.0,221.0" style="Tableau1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <blockTable colWidths="250.0" style="Tableau2">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <para style="terp_default_Bold_9"><b>Expected Delivery address:</b></para>
                <para style="terp_default_9">[[ (order.dest_address_id and order.dest_address_id.name) or (order.warehouse_id and order.warehouse_id.name) or '']]</para>
                <para style="P1">[[ order.dest_address_id and display_address(order.dest_address_id) ]]</para>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </blockTable>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_default_9">[[ (order .partner_id and order.partner_id.title and order.partner_id.title.name) or '' ]] [[ (order .partner_id and order.partner_id.name) or '' ]] </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">[[ order.partner_id and display_address(order .partner_id) ]] </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">Tel.: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.phone) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">Fax: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.fax) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
          <para style="P1">TVA: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.vat) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
    <para style="Standard">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_header"><b>Request for Quotation : [[order.name]]</b></para>
    <para style="terp_default_8">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <blockTable colWidths="371.0,98.0,61.0" repeatRows="1" style="Table_Product_Header_Title">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details"><b>Description</b></para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre"><b>Expected Date</b></para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre"><b>Qty</b></para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
    <section>
      <para style="terp_default_9">[[ repeatIn(order.order_line,'order_line') ]]</para>
      <blockTable colWidths="371.0,98.0,61.0" style="Table_Product_Line">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[ order_line.name ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Centre_9">[[ formatLang(order_line.date_planned, date = True) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">
                [[ formatLang(order_line.product_qty )]]
                <i>[[ (order_line.product_uom and order_line.product_uom.name) or '' ]]</i>
            </para>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
    </section>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ format(order.notes or '') ]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">Regards,</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="Space bet user and signature">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ user.signature or '' ]]</para>
  </story>
</document>
```

then override report to be like this

```
<report auto="False" id="report_purchase_quotation" model="purchase.order" 
                name="purchase.quotation" rml="purchase_extra_report/report/request_quotation.rml"
                string="Request for Quotation" header="False"/>
```

when i install my module it installed but when try to print`quotation
I got this error
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
id=2&view_type=form&model=purchase.order&menu_id=423&action=547:0 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<document filename="requestforquotation.pdf">
   <template title="Purchase Order" author="OpenERP S.A.(sales@openerp.com)" allowSplitting="20">

     <pageTemplate>
        <frame id="first" x1="1.3cm" y1="3.0cm" height="21.7cm" width="19.0cm"/>
         <stylesheet>
            <!-- Set here the default font to use for all <para> tags -->
            <paraStyle name='Normal' fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
            <paraStyle name="main_footer" fontSize="8.0" alignment="CENTER"/>
            <paraStyle name="main_header" fontSize="8.0" leading="10" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
         </stylesheet>
        <pageGraphics>
            <!-- Set here the default font to use for all <drawString> tags -->
            <setFont name="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
            <!-- You Logo - Change X,Y,Width and Height -->
            <image x="1.3cm" y="27.7cm" height="40.0" >[[ company.logo or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
            <fill color="black"/>
            <stroke color="black"/>

            <!-- page header -->
            <lines>1.3cm 27.7cm 20cm 27.7cm</lines>
            <drawRightString x="20cm" y="27.8cm">[[ company.rml_header1 ]]</drawRightString>
            <drawString x="1.3cm" y="27.3cm">[[ company.partner_id.name ]]</drawString>
            <place x="1.3cm" y="25.3cm" height="1.8cm" width="15.0cm">
                <para style="main_header">[[ display_address(company.partner_id) or  '' ]]</para>
            </place>
            <drawString x="1.3cm" y="25.0cm">Phone:</drawString>
            <drawRightString x="7cm" y="25.0cm">[[ company.partner_id.phone or '' ]]</drawRightString>
            <drawString x="1.3cm" y="24.6cm">Mail:</drawString>
            <drawRightString x="7cm" y="24.6cm">[[ company.partner_id.email or '' ]]</drawRightString>
            <lines>1.3cm 24.5cm 7cm 24.5cm</lines>

            <!-- left margin -->
            <rotate degrees="90"/>
            <fill color="black"/>
            <rotate degrees="-90"/>

            <!--page bottom-->
            <lines>1.2cm 2.65cm 19.9cm 2.65cm</lines>
            <place x="1.3cm" y="0cm" height="2.55cm" width="19.0cm">
                <para style="main_footer">التالية‬ ‫الشروط‬ ‫توافر‬ ‫حالة‬ ‫في‬ ‫فقط‬ ‫أعاله‬ ‫املذكور‬ ‫التاريخ‬ ‫في‬ ‫املبلغ‬ ‫بدفع‬ ‫الشركة‬ ‫تلتزم‬
‫البضاعة‬ ‫تسليم‬ ‫تاريخ‬ ‫من‬ ‫يومني‬ ‫أقصى‬ ‫بحد‬ ‫املبلغ‬ ‫بنفس‬ ‫املورد‬ ‫من‬ ‫البيع‬ ‫
‫
                </para>
                <para style="main_footer">Contact : [[ user.name ]] - Page: <pageNumber/></para>
            </place>
        </pageGraphics>
    </pageTemplate>

    </template>
  <stylesheet>
    <blockTableStyle id="Standard_Outline">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Tableau1">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Tableau2">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Table_Product_Header_Title">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="0,-1" stop="0,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="1,-1" stop="1,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" start="2,-1" stop="2,-1"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <blockTableStyle id="Table_Product_Line">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="0,-1" stop="0,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="1,-1" stop="1,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="2,-1" stop="2,-1"/>
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#e6e6e6" start="3,-1" stop="3,-1"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
    <initialize>
      <paraStyle name="all" alignment="justify"/>
    </initialize>
    <paraStyle name="P1" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="Standard"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_header" fontSize="12.0" leading="15" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="12.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_tblheader_Details" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="6.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_8" fontSize="8.0" leading="10" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="6.0" spaceAfter="6.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Bold_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Centre_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="terp_default_Right_9" fontSize="9.0" leading="11" alignment="RIGHT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <paraStyle name="Space bet user and signature" fontSize="4.0" leading="5" alignment="LEFT" spaceBefore="0.0" spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <images/>
  </stylesheet>
  <story>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[repeatIn(objects,'order')]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ setLang(order.partner_id.lang) ]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <blockTable colWidths="250.0,59.0,221.0" style="Tableau1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <blockTable colWidths="250.0" style="Tableau2">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <para style="terp_default_Bold_9"><b>Expected Delivery address:</b></para>
                <para style="terp_default_9">[[ (order.dest_address_id and order.dest_address_id.name) or (order.warehouse_id and order.warehouse_id.name) or '']]</para>
                <para style="P1">[[ order.dest_address_id and display_address(order.dest_address_id) ]]</para>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </blockTable>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_default_9">[[ (order .partner_id and order.partner_id.title and order.partner_id.title.name) or '' ]] [[ (order .partner_id and order.partner_id.name) or '' ]] </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">[[ order.partner_id and display_address(order .partner_id) ]] </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">
            <font color="white"> </font>
          </para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">Tel.: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.phone) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
          <para style="terp_default_9">Fax: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.fax) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
          <para style="P1">TVA: [[ (order.partner_id and order.partner_id.vat) or removeParentNode('para') ]]</para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
    <para style="Standard">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_header"><b>Request for Quotation : [[order.name]]</b></para>
    <para style="terp_default_8">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <blockTable colWidths="371.0,98.0,61.0" repeatRows="1" style="Table_Product_Header_Title">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details"><b>Description</b></para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre"><b>Expected Date</b></para>
        </td>
        <td>
          <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Centre"><b>Qty</b></para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
    <section>
      <para style="terp_default_9">[[ repeatIn(order.order_line,'order_line') ]]</para>
      <blockTable colWidths="371.0,98.0,61.0" style="Table_Product_Line">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[ order_line.name ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Centre_9">[[ formatLang(order_line.date_planned, date = True) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">
                [[ formatLang(order_line.product_qty )]]
                <i>[[ (order_line.product_uom and order_line.product_uom.name) or '' ]]</i>
            </para>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
    </section>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ format(order.notes or '') ]]</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">Regards,</para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="Space bet user and signature">
      <font color="white"> </font>
    </para>
    <para style="terp_default_9">[[ user.signature or '' ]]</para>
  </story>
</document>
```

the problem was that i used style which is not defined in my rml ,but the arabic words printed not correctly